# Make a private member without using Instance Ids Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a LinkedList class and I want to make the `head` member of the instance private. I see how I could create a key id for each instance and those hide the member of users of the LinkedList class. Looking for some other way to make `this.head` private

```js
function LinkedList() {
    this.head = null;
};

LinkedList.prototype = (function () {
    function reverseAll(current, prev) {
        if (!current.next) { //we have the head
            this.head = current;
            this.head.next = prev;
        }

        var next = current.next;
        current.next = prev;

        reverseAll(next, current);
    };

    return {
        constructor: LinkedList,

        reverse: function () {
            reverseAll(this.head, null);
        },

        head: function() {
            return this.head;
        }
    }
})();

LinkedList.prototype.add = function(value) {
    var node = {
        value: value,
        next: null
    };

    var current;

    if (this.head === null) {
        this.head = node;
    } else {
        current = this.head;
        while (current.next) {
            current = current.next;
        }
        current.next = node;
    }

    return node;
}

LinkedList.prototype.remove = function(node) {
    var current, value = node.value;

    if (this.head !== null) {
        if (this.head === node) {
            this.head = this.head.next;
            node.next = null;
            return value;
        }
        //find node if node not head
        current = this.head;
        while (current.next) {
            if (current.next === node) {
                current.next = node.next;
                return value;
            }

            current = current.next;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    var obj = new LinkedList();
    
    for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        obj.add(i);
    }
  
  console.log(obj.head);
  obj.head = 'pwned';
  console.log(obj.head);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is some sort of abomination like this:

```
function LinkedList() {
    let head = null; 
    // Instead of using a prototype, you attach the methods directly to this.
    // This makes the methods unique per instance, so you can attach privately
    // scoped variables (like head).
    this.reverse = function() { 
        // You may use head here.
    };
    this.head = function() { ... };
}
```

However, this is *highly* inefficient as you'll create an entirely new set of closures with each invocation.

Even solutions like the module pattern (or the revealing module pattern) suffer from this problem. If you aren't creating too many of this object, the above example might be for you.

Comment: using let means I cannot access head in my prototypes correct?

Comment: Yes. You give up the ability to prototype for this. Also, it's not unique to `let`, I could have used `var` there for the same effect. It's just that `let` is the recommended* way to initialize variables in ES6.

Comment: These are not attached to your prototype. They are methods of the object initialized by the constructor.